# How can I write in other languages in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, typography, text, glyphs

In other languages, alphabets can combine characters into symbols. I don't know if Photoshop can do that. Is there a clean way to do it, or a special **plugin** (preferably free)?. Maybe there is some hackish way like opening 3 programs and then writing in one, clearing in 2nd and then pasting in 3rd.

I mean Photoshop is used in other non english countries. What do they do? Or Adobe doesn't care about them?

Comment: Adobe applications are available in multiple language versions.

Comment: @Muhammad: Different language input methods are a wide field. Primarily, it depends on the operating system and  keyboard settings which Photoshop should then work with as well. Could you name languages you have in mind or link to an image/text for example?

Comment: Urdu, Chinese, and Arabic.

Comment: Microsoft word seems to understand all other fonts completely. And mix them appropriately.

Comment: heck even in start menu its writing the language correctly.

Comment: It's working here fine too!!! LOOK "کےا لکد کجیک کجلکج ", I just wrote comments in foregin language on youtube. Another interesting thing i noticed that layers get names after text that is inside the text layer, right..And its showing there correctly. Layer's Name of Type/text is showing as it should look like but the text itself is not.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge goes all you need is a font that is available in your language of preference to be installed on to your machine (provided it should be a photoshop compliant font). In my case I used a Hindi font with ease provided I had a Hindi keyboard layout available with me. I did this using Adobe Photoshop CS4. Hence if you're using a CS5 or a CS6 the software would be backward compatible and would serve the same way as it did in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the frustration of the OP, @Muhammad Umer. You very well may want to contact [WinSoft](http://www.winsoft-international.com/), for they make many tools to help Arabic, Hebrew and other languages comprised of symbols flow correctly. The bulk of the issue for Adobe, I assume, is that they concentrate complex text, H&J's and language controls within InDesign CS6.

InDesign would likely be the answer to how to best layout Arabic text. Place the Photoshop image within InDesign and design/layout from there in Arabic or the language you need to use. With the Worldready plugin from InDesign, this is largely possible, yet still many opt for *InDesign ME* from WinSoft for deeper Middle Eastern language and text layout control.

That said, Adobe does have tools and even a special "layer" PSD file to help specifically with Arabic or right to left flowing languages in Photoshop. You need to change your language settings in Photoshop and indeed need the proper fonts and keyboard (or keyboard overlay), but it is possible. See: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3407321
I hope this helps.

Comment: ok this layer works...but shouldn't there be like built in feature for this.

Comment: Nvm That Layer has bugs in it. Still having troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Search for Fonts online, wide variety of fonts in all language is available. Just download it and try typing using text tool. That's it.

Comment: it just writes alphabets, it doesnt combine them as they should.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you just cant write that easily. Did you try visiting http://www.google.com/transliterate. I believe almost all language is there, you can type it and install the same font used by google in your desktop/pc and paste it. Just have a try.
Make sure before pasting the data to install the same font or compatible fonts with that of google fonts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Chinese keyboards (for example) are different from English ones. With a combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> and a particular letter, you can write many different symbols. It is similar in Polish just with less possibilities available (as we don't have so many own letters). It is actually not annoying nor uncomfortable at all once you get used to it (or use it for all your life).

Of course, the font must have symbols you want to use; searching for it may be a little troublesome.

[Here you can see what a Chinese keyboard](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Keyboard_layout_Chinese_Traditional.png) looks like.