# How do I type Arabic text in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, cs6, arabic

I want to type Arabic text in Photoshop, but the text appears disjointed and the letters do not connect at all. For example محمد appears as م ح م د.

I'm using Photoshop CS6 on OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: Related questions: [Make Arabic text show properly in Adobe Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/8154/408) and [How can I write in other languages in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/16497/408).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To type Arabic or Hebrew in Photoshop, you need to enable the Middle Eastern text engine.  You can do this by going to Preferences > Type.  Check out this video: [How to access Arabic and Hebrew features in Photoshop CS6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfuw7m5mVTk)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this website : http://www.arabic-keyboard.org/photoshop-arabic/

Just write or paste your text in the first box, then click on the COPY button and PASTE in Photoshop.

Comment: Nice. In some browsers (e.g. Chrome) it seems like the Copy button doesn't work but copying the text out of the lower box then pasting it into Photoshop seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. I know how to type Arabic text. Photoshop breaks the lettes appart upon pasting them.

Comment: For me (CS6 on Lion) it *does* keep the joins, so long as you copy from the ***lower* of the two input boxes** (the one where in the web browser, it looks like the text has been reversed). For example, for me محمد appears as ﺪﻤﺤﻣ in the browser but does then paste into photoshop as محمد, with each character joined.

Comment: easy and direct

Answer (score 3):

In order to type Arabic text in English versions of Photoshop you need to download an Arabic enabled text layer and use it as a template, duplicating it for each block of Arabic text you need.

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4106

Comment: This works with the CC version too. Anyways, for Windows OS: https://supportdownloads.adobe.com/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=4107&fileID=3813

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is download arabic writing software i.e. [Google IME arabic](http://www.google.com/inputtools/windows/), then write your text in MS Paint save it as picture (i.e. JPG or MPEG) now import the picture in photoshop thats it.